# Iterating through a li tag with Selenium not getting .text from first two elements of the list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to iterate through a li tag on https://game-rainbow6.ubi.com/en-us/uplay/player-statistics/dbd1cef3-d69d-4296-a235-ae8d7d70363f/multiplayer in the operator tab(selecting the tab doesn't change the link, sorry) I have no trouble getting to the tab, but when I get the li tag and iterate through it to get all the four web elements I need(name, time played, k/d,w/l) it skips the first two operators in the list. It prints the rest just fine. I tried and implicit wait to just see if maybe the first two weren't loading as fast, but that didn't work, I then tried the explicit wait that is in the code right now, but it times out every time. I also tried finding the elements by xpath. This is the complete xpath to the first operator name

```
//*[@id="section"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/article[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p
```

I tried to do

```
.//div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p
```

in the for loop as I just needed the tail end of the path for each element, but it still skips the first two operators.

I created a test login so people can look at the html properly:

```
email = UbiTest1337@gmail.com
pwd = Password1

def scrapeOperatorStats(self):
    #navigate to operator tab
    operator_tab = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="section"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/article[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button')

    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", operator_tab)
    #wait for operator stats elements to load
 WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="section"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/article[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p')))

    #Get the li tag that is a list of all operators and thier respective stats
    operator_list_set = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="section"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/article[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/ul')
    operators = operator_list_set.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

    for operator in operators:
        operator_stats = operator.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
        for stat in operator_stats:
            print(stat.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use get_attribute('innerHTML') and it will get all the elements, you dont even need to switch tabs.

```
    #Get the li tag that is a list of all operators and thier respective stats
    operator_list_set = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="section"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/article[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/nav/ul')
    operators = operator_list_set.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

    for operator in operators:
        operator_stats = operator.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
        for stat in operator_stats:
            print(stat.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```